# Input field dropdown list doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, backbone.js

I have this input field where the user can enter a suggested price for a purchase. In every browser when the user clickes on the field to enter the price a dropdown list opens with more suggested prices.

```
<span class="text-input">
<input type="text" class="price" name="value" data-round="false" data-min="1" data-max="1000" value="'+this.model.get('price')+'" list="price-values-" />
</span>
```

Only in IE9 the user can enter the price by clicking on the field but the list with the suggested prices does not open. Any idea??

fyi: I use backbone.js

I am using HTML 5 datalist and this is how I call it:`$(".price" ,this.el).dataList();`

Comment: And... where are the errors? the code block or something more informative?

Comment: Are you using just the list attribute and the datalist element? These are not supported in IE9. http://caniuse.com/#search=list

Comment: There are no errors.. There is a compatibility issue. The code is good.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

Comment: What are you using to render the dropdown list? Is it some jQuery plugin or are you simply using a datalist as others have suggested. You'll need to provide more information.

Comment: I just edited it..@BartJedrocha